# Title aligning at bottomNavigationView

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I have removed icons at items of bottomNavigationView, and I have the following menu right now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/received_messages"
        android:title="Received" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/sent_messages"
        android:title="Sent" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/draft_messages"
        android:title="Draft" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/delete_messages"
        android:title="Delete" />
</menu>
```

and bottomNav at xml layout:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_ms"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:theme="@style/Widget.BottomNavigationView"
        app:itemBackground="@color/bottom_color_2"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selected_text_2"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/selected_text_2"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
        app:menu="@menu/message_center_menu" />
```

but right now I have all titles at the bottom of each item. Can smb help me to centralize titles horisontally and vertically?

### UPDATE

new xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_ms"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:theme="@style/Widget.BottomNavigationView"
        app:itemBackground="@color/bottom_color_2"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selected_text_2"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/selected_text_2"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
        app:menu="@menu/message_center_menu" />
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add this two attributes. I have tested them. works perfectly.

```
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
```